# Android ListView animation error

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I got this ListView:

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSpinner.clearAnimation();
                }
                });

            // populate list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Profile profile : friends) {
                //profile.getInstalled();
                values.add(profile.getName());
            }

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, final View view, final int i, long i2) {

                  Animation pushLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SendActivity.this, R.anim.animation);
                  view.startAnimation(pushLeftIn);

            }
            });

            ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_items2, values);
            friendsListAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);    
                }
            });
            mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsListAdapter);
        }
    };
```

I have tried adding a animation when you click an item inside the ListView using this code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, final View view, final int i, long i2) {

                  Animation pushLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SendActivity.this, R.anim.animation);
                  view.startAnimation(pushLeftIn);

            }
            });
```

The ListView fetches facebook friends, and loads them in the list, when i open the ListView inside the app it doesnt load at all, and i get this LogCat error:

```
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223): Bad thing happened
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at com.example.test.SendActivity$1.onComplete(SendActivity.java:103)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at com.example.test.SendActivity$1.onComplete(SendActivity.java:1)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at com.sromku.simple.fb.actions.GetAction$1.onCompleted(GetAction.java:48)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1670)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04-29 17:46:13.492: E/com.example.test.SendActivity(14223):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What seems to be wrong with the code and what should i add or change to make it work?

Comment: the error is from the request to facebook

Comment: I got the error after i added in the animation code, before that the list loaded facebook friends properly :)

Comment: so the animation it is just translating to the left?

Comment: yes but i tried with different animations and got same error for all

Answer (score 0):

You can try this animation without using any xml..

```
view.animate().setDuration(500).translationX(100)
```

Comment: @da_st is onComplete callback run on background threaD?

Comment: hm not really sure how can i check that?